# Passing params through ui-router to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some troubles with geting single user basing on his ID. I can remove this certain user with DELETE in my app but I can't get informations about him using "GET".

this is my angular app.js

```
app.controller('editUser', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $http.get('users/editUser/'+$state.params.userId).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

and this is my users.js routes file

```
router.get('/editUser/:userId', ensureAuthenticated, function(res, req, next) {
    var userId= req.params.userId,
        data;

    getUser.findOne({'_id': userId}, function(err, user) {
         if(err) throw err;
         data = user;
         res.json(data);
     });
});
```

after clicking on "edit" button I am redirected to users/editUser/ffw23rfaw - its id, and basing on this id I use get function to get info about him but I get 500 "Internal server error". I would like to add that removing user is pretty much same and it works.

after clicking Edit button I do this

```
$scope.editUser = function($index) {
        $state.go('editUser', {userId: $index});
    }
```

that's how I get userId on 'users/editUser/' page

and this is my state config

```
    .state('editUser', {
        url: '/users/editUser/:userId',
        templateUrl: '/views/editUser.html'
    })
```

Comment: need to uncomment the braces needed to close `getUser.findOne()`. What are you seeing in your node console?

Comment: 500 Internal error means something is breaking the code on your server side. Can you post some more details about the error? Maybe a snapshot.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I just didnt remove all coments before posting here. On my pc theres no comments there

Comment: your user schema is called getUser ??, don't think so ...

Comment: @ZeRubeus yes it is

Comment: @AhsanAyaz damn I totally forgot about printing errors to git console.. this is my error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined' so somehow userId is undefined?

Comment: if I print console.log('$state.params); in my controller (angular) then it shows in console that userId = gawg3tw349tw

Comment: @ZeRubeus yes it is, the error shows that userId is not passing somehow

Comment: @HulkBulk, check my answer ! I hope that would resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue :) 
Your code has `function(res, req, next)`
Change that to

```
function(req, res, next)
```

just wrong placement of parameters (variable names). 
Hope this helps. (thanks for pointing out the console message)

Comment: LIFE SAVER! :) damn I just type to fast xd

Comment: We all do :D No problem !